# Metro C++/XAML ListView Snapped Item

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a ListView that looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Text="{Binding Path=TitleCategory}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Body" Text="{Binding Path=BodySummary}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextStyle}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The BodyTextStyle I apply to that TextBlock sets the width at 600px, and everything displays fine in FullScreenLandscape. However,  when I switch into SnappedView, the text clips off due to the decreased screen width. Normally I'd set the width like so:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="Body">
  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="300"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

But this produces a runtime crash, I assume because the item(s) I'm referencing are in an ItemTemplate. What is the correct way to change the width of every item in my ListView when I go into SnappedView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have seen in the samples and templates the recommended way seems to be to provide a separate ListView for the different view state and after trying to optimize it by trying to do something similar to what you are doing and having to fight a lot of issues I've decided to give up and do what the templates do.
Save yourself the trouble and use a separate ListView for the snapped view and simply switch visibilities of both ListViews when the view state changes.

Also I would assume that you are right and the problem comes from the name scope issue with templates having separate name scopes.

Comment: Ended up going this route, not exactly happy about the code redundancy, but until I find a better solution this will have to do =\